# Anyone has table of piercing and damage for each tower in bloon tower defense?

Tags: bloons-td-5

For example

http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Bomb_Tower says that it hits 10 times as much against MOAB.

Well, 10 times what?

How many hits, for example, from a moab mauler would pop a zomg?

I know a fully upgraded triple darts monkey can penetrate 4 bloons but only take 1 life from each bloon. Also they throw 3 darts per throw. Total dps is 12 per throw. How many frames per attack, however?

Where can I get a complete data?

Snipper tower takes 23 hits to hit. ZOMG itself takes 5500 normal hits to pop. How many time do we have to hit with bomb tower (or any other tower) to pop it?

It seems to me that each tower have pierce and damage. For example death beam has 100 pierce but only one damage and hence not very good for zomg. I want to know the value for each.

Answer (score 3):

The best source I've found is a [forum post](http://archive.ninjakiwi.com/Forum/showthread.php/19457-Popping-power-of-Every-tower-in-BTD5).  Here's the content:

> Dart monkey
>   0/0: 1 / 11
>   3/0: 18 / 28
>   3/1: 19 / 29
>   3/2: 21 / 31
>   4/0: 100 / 110
>   4/1: 101 / 111
>   4/2: 103 / 113
>   0/1: 2 / 12
>   0/2: 4 / 14
>   0/3: 4 x 3 = 12 / 14 x 3 = 42
>   Splodey Darts: +10 after dart pops.
>
> Tack Shooter/Tack Awesomizer
>   0/0: 1 x 8 / 2 x 8 = 16
>   3/0: 1 x 16 / 2 x 16 = 32
>   4/0: 60 / 120 (A bug makes that 61 now)
>   0/3: 2 x 8 = 16 / 4 x 8 = 32
>   0/4: Infinity
>   Specialty/Tack Awesomizer
>   0/0: 2 x 8 = 16 / 3 x 8 = 24
>   3/0: 2 x 16 = 32 / 3 x 16 = 48
>   4/0: 61 / 122 (A bug makes that 62)
>   0/3: 3 x 8 = 24 / 6 x 8 = 48
>
> Sniper Monkey/Rifle Range
>   0/0: 2 layers / 3 layers
>   1/0: 4 layers / 5 layers
>   2/0: 7 layers / 8 layers
>   3/0: 18 layers / 19 layers
>
> Boomerang Thrower/Double Ranga
>   0/0: 3 / 3 x 2 = 6
>   1/0: 7 / 7 x 2 = 14
>   2/0: 12 / 12 x 2 = 24
>   3/0: 101 / 101 x 2 = 202
>   4/0: 10000 to orbiting glaives
>
> Ninja Monkey
>   0/0: 2
>   2/0: 4
>   3/0: 4 x 2 = 8
>   4/0: 4 x 5 = 20
>   x/3: 30
>
> Bomb Tower
>   0/0: 40
>   0/1: 50
>   2/0: 40 + 8 = 48
>   2/1: 50 + 8 = 58
>   3/0: 40 x 9 = 360
>   3/1: 50 x 9 = 450
>   0/3: 10 damage to blimps
>   0/4: 700 damage to blimps
>
> Ice tower
>   0/0: 10000
>   0/3: 1 per shard
>   x/4: infinite
>
> Glue Gunner
>   0/0: 1
>   x/2: 6
>   x/3: 12
>   x/4: infinite
>
> Monkey Buccaneer
>   0/0: 5
>   0/1: 5 + 1 x 4 = 9
>   4/0: 5 x 8 + 5 x 2 for a plane = 50
>   0/3: 5 + 1 x 4 + 30 = 39
>
> Monkey Ace
>   0/0: 15 x 8 = 120
>   2/0: 18 x 8 = 144
>   4/0: 18 + 40 = 58 for one
>   0/1: 40
>   0/3: 15 x 16 = 240
>   2/3: 18 x 16 = 288
>   0/4: infinite, 500 damage to blimps
>
> Super Monkey
>   0/0: 1
>   1/0: 1 x 2
>   2/0: 3
>   3/0: 15 x 3 per frame
>   4/0: so big it's hard to find out
>   0/3: 3
>   1/3: 4
>   2/3: 5
>   0/4: 5
>   1/4: 6
>   2/4: 7
>   Ability: +250000
>
> Monkey Apprentice
>   0/0: 2
>   1/0: 7
>   2/0: 7, 25
>   3/0: 7, 25, 20
>   4/0: 7, 25, 70
>   0/1: 40
>   0/3: 4 per frame
>   0/4: 2 per frame
>   Homing: 7
>   Tiny tornadoes: don't know, don't have this premium.
>
> Village
>   4/0: 1 per frame, 2 layers per frame
>   0/1: grants +1 to all towers except sniper
>   0/4: doubles popping power for all towers except sniper
>
> Mortar
>   0/0: 40
>   4/0: 100
>   ability: infinite
>
> Dartling
>   0/0: 1
>   3/0: 13
>   4/0: 100
>   0/1: 3
>   3/1: 15
>   0/3: 40
>   0/4: 40 x 3 = 120
>   Ability: 500 x 40 = 2000
>
> Spike Factory/Tack Awesomizer
>   0/0: 5 / 10
>   1/0: 10 / 20
>   3/0: 16 / 32
>   4/0: 16 + 20 / 32 + 40
>   0/3: 15 damage to MOABs
>   1/3: 30 damage to MOABs
>   0/4: 1000 / 2000
>   1/4: 2000 / 4000
>
> Monkey Engineer
>   0/0: 3
>   Sentry: 2
>   3/0: need further tests
>   4/0: 250
>   0/1: 8
>
> Bloonchipper
>   0/0: 250 RBE
>   4/0: 600 damage to blimps
>   0/3: 750 RBE

Levels are shown as left path/right path.  In a number / number, the first number is the base number and the second number is with the appropriate premium or specialty building.  For example, Tack Awesomizer doubles the pierce for Tack Shooters and doubles the spiking of Spike Factories.